# read.bib gives lex fatal error - end of buffer missed, {bibtex} package

Tags: r, lex, bibtex

I am attempting to create a script which will distribute a number of pdfs into a folder tree according to tags. I have the file metadata (including filepath) in a bibtex format. I have tried a number of work-arounds to import the metadata, but so far have been unable to get the filepath, year, title, and tags into a single data frame.

When I try to import using read.bib (which seems the simplest solution) I get the following error:

> dbase_full <- read.bib("C:/Users/WILIAM-PLAN/Desktop/My Collection 23 07.bib")
>
> Error in read.bib("C:/Users/WILIAM-PLAN/Desktop/My Collection 23 07.bib") :
>
> lex fatal error:
>
> fatal flex scanner internal error--end of buffer missed

I have looked up the error but language of the 'under the hood' part of the {bibtex} package (lex scanners etc) is beyond me.

Is there quick fix for this error?
If not, is there another way to get the file metadata from bibtex into a dataframe?

Comment: reproducible example?

Comment: Please submit an issue here: https://github.com/romainfrancois/bibtex/issues

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem.
The problem is that in the bib file could be in some fields  (as abstract) lines with a lot of chars..
You need to split and wrap them.
I hope it is useful